# Help Identifying 1050C chip

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image: 1050]

Could someone identify this part?

Comment: Where have U looked?

Comment: Since it's labelled "Q16" it's likely a transistor (or pair of them). Some context, like what the circuit does and what that part is connected to would be helpful.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75
Its located before the DC IN Jack 19V

Comment: @brhans



https://imgur.com/a/CbRkxLl
This is the first gen showing 10552,

Comment: You can diode test every pin and report back

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75
It's faulty, all of the output pins are shorted to ground.

Comment: @kleultsof , have you found it? My shield tv is also broken, need to replace this 1050C chip, would you share the replacement part number?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the wider image (cropped):

[image]

I've rotated it for as-yet no obvious reason, but we see U15 is a "TI" chip with "53015" on it.  This is a [TPS53015](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps53015.pdf), a synchronous buck converter in MSOP-10 package.  Two external transistors are used, likely Q16 (the question) and Q15 (unreadable).  Q15 is larger, probably because the output voltage is quite low (3.3 to 5V, perhaps?).

Taking a look at the datasheet application section, we find a suggested layout:

[image]

Looks very familiar to the rotated view; it's likely they followed this reference.  Q16 then must be a SOT-23-6 N-MOSFET.  It seems to have the standard footprint.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a likely ID for the transistor.  By the description, it's very likely N-ch, 30 or 40V, and some number of amperes.